# Calling svn diff on some revision and previous revision, with no local copy

Tags: linux, svn, unix

I have no local copies of any files from the SVN repository. I do have a full path URL to some file in SVN. How can I see the difference between revision 1234 of that file, and it's previous revision, whatever it may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn diff -c 1234 $URL`

Assuming you are using a version of Subversion newer than 1.4 when -c was added.  Otherwise you need to do:

`svn diff -r 1233:1234 $URL`

If you want to see a diff including changes across multiple revisions you can just expand the revision numbers you provide to `-r`.

You can see detailed documentation of the [diff subcommand in the SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html).